# SQL Server 2008 side-by-side with SQL Server 2012, possible issues with SAP Business One 8.81 PL:07?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sap

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise system running SQL Server 2008 Enterprise (x64) version 10.0.4067.0 and SAP Business One 8.81 PL:07. We would like to install a named instance of SQL Server 2012 (side-by-side with 2008), leaving all the 2008 databases in place. I have tried to find a reference of some sort to determine if there are any problems with a 2012 side-by-side install, but have had no luck. I have not seen anywhere that SQL Server 2012 is supported with our version of SAP, but it is my thinking that doing a side-by-side install instead of an upgrade would allow SAP/SQL 2008 to continue working as they are. Am I wrong? Any thoughts or advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be fine as DanBig mentioned.  Database engines can live harmoniously.  Other SQL Server components (like Integration Services) can have issues.  Whether or not SAP will be happy with that - *shrug*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install just about any versions of SQL side by side, you only need to have separate instance names. We have several locations with your particular installation with no issue.

Your current applications that rely on SQL 2008 will not be affected by adding a 2012 instance side by side.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for the response. Will be installing today or tomorrow. Will mark as answer then.

Comment: When installing, is it advisable to select "All Features With Defaults" or should I specify features and service accounts?

Comment: There is no reason to install all features, unless you need all features. Install based on your needs. If you don't need things like Full Text Search or Integration svcs, don't install.